# can anyone tell me if this an Onto function?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Suppose f : Z x Z → Z is defined as f (x, y) = x+ y². Is the function onto?

I have tried this approach

Z x Z = A

Z = B

Any value for b s.t b is an element of Z

f(x,y)= x+y²= b

Let x= 3b

Let y = √-2b

Substituting the values of x and y

3b + (√-2b)² = b

3b -2b =b

b=b

So, f(3b,√-2b) are the values for x and y. Since square root of a negative number is an imaginary number. y cannot be an element of Z. Thus proved that this function is not an onto.

Is my approach correct. It will be very helpful if you can give some hints IF I am doing something wrong.

Comment: What is an onto function in this context? If you have a value you want for $z$ can you always get this value by choosing some $x$ and $y$?

Comment: Hint: consider fixing y=$0$.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is not correct. It is because you chose $b=f(x,y)\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $y=\sqrt{-2b}$, which is not an integer. The problem is that $(x,y)\in\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ and thus $y$ should be an integer. Furthermore, the function you provided is indeed onto.

Recall that a function $f:A\to B$ is said to be onto if for any $b\in B$ there exists some $a\in A$ such that $f(a)=b$.

So, what you have to do is to show that for any $b\in\mathbb{Z}$ (i.e. for any $b$ in your codomain), find some $(x,y)\in\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ (i.e. $(x,y)$ in your domain) such that $f(x,y)=b$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I realized the mistake. I watched a lot of Youtube videos and read about proving onto function . This was my first practice without solution given. Guess I need to practice more.  I have fully understood the concept of onto . For every b in codomain B , there must be atleast one a in domain A such that f(a) = b. If I take y = 0 as hinted by Zanzag. and x = b then , f(x,y) = x+y² = b.  ----   b + 0² =b ----- b=b. So we have found an a in A which can output f(a) = b . So this is an onto function. Thanks